# No response in python

Tags: python

I wrote a simple code for:
enter any number and a digit and count how many times the digit is in the number.

the code i wrote is:

```
num= int(input("enter a number"))
n=num
digit = int(input("enter the digit"))
times=0
while n > 0 :
    d = n%10
    if d==digit :
        times += 1
        continue
    else:
        continue
    n=n//10
print ("no. of times digit gets repeated is ", times)
```

When I tried this code, somehow it gave me nothing

Comment: Gave you nothing as in? An infinite loop?

Comment: Your loop always hits a `continue` before it reaches `n=n//10`. It's an infinite loop.

Comment: maybe @Astrian_72954

Comment: @muzaafnameerfirdausi Then its bcs of ```continue``` beore ```n=n//10```

Comment: Remove the else part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `else` and `continue` statements because the loop always hits the `continue` and never goes to `n=n//10`

```
num= int(input("enter a number"))
n=num
digit = int(input("enter the digit"))
times=0
while n > 0 :
    d = n%10
    if d==digit :
        times += 1
    n=n//10
print ("no. of times digit gets repeated is ", times)
```

Output:

```
enter a number1111222233344567433232222222
enter the digit2
no. of times digit gets repeated is  12
```

Comment: @muzaafnameerfirdausi accept the answer if it has solved your problem

Comment: i will in 8 mins

Comment: @muzaafnameerfirdausi Remember you have completely free choice which answer to accept.

Answer (score 2):

```
if d==digit :
    times += 1
    continue
else:
    continue
n=n//10
```

There is *no* way to reach the code line above that divides `n` by ten because both the true and false branches restart the loop with `continue`, hence `n` will *never* change value and you'll loop forever (for non-zero number input).

You should remove `continue` from *both* branches and, in fact, you don't *need* the `else` part since it doesn't do anything:

```
if d == digit:
    times += 1
n = n // 10
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `n=n//10` never gets executed because of the `continue`s before it. You don't need continue if you don't intend to skip the remaining of this loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers point out your `continue` misuse, but there're a couple Pythonic ways to do this.

[`divmod()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) neatly does division and modulus in one operation:

```
num = int(input("enter a number"))
digit = int(input("enter the digit"))
times = 0
while num > 0:
    num, d = divmod(num, 10)
    if d == digit:
        times += 1

print("no. of times digit gets repeated is ", times)
```

You can also more simply not do anything with numbers, but with strings, and use `str.count`:

```
num = input("enter a number")
digit = input("enter the digit")
print("no. of times digit gets repeated is ", num.count(digit))
```